# My Postgres Log is giving tons of these errors. And I am not sure what is happening

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.4

```
2012-04-23 16:35:07 PDTWARNING:  nonstandard use of \\ in a string literal at character 117
2012-04-23 16:35:07 PDTHINT:  Use the escape string syntax for backslashes, e.g., E'\\'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recent PostgreSQL, strings are supposed to conform to the standard, which means no escaping -- by default.  There are settings to control this:

- `standard_conforming_strings` -- defaults to on since 9.1.
- `escape_string_warning` -- also defaults to on.

Which means a string literal like `'a\nb'` is parsed as 4 simple characters.  If you want it to parsed with escapes, there is a syntax `E'a\nb'` which will parse it as the 3 expected characters.  See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-compatible.html for a proper explanation.

I suspect (if you are running a PostgreSQL 9.1 or later), that you have `standard_conforming_strings = off` -- possibly to let legacy queries written using escapes run correctly.  The warning is still enabled however, because it's warning you that you're using deprecated syntax.

The proper solution is to fix all your queries to use the `E` prefix, if you want to get rid of the warning.  Assuming of course that the escapes are intentional -- if not, then setting `standard_conforming_strings = on` is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You're inserting/updating using a value that contains an unescaped back-slash, eg `abc\def`, when you should escape it like this `abc\\def`.

Examine/debug your input data to find the problem text

Comment: Thanks Bohemian. I am using rss feeds to insert data into my database so I am not sure what the data would be like. Can we have something which will escape these characters automatically.?

Comment: If you're using java, JDBC will do it for you automatically. Other languages, I don't know. You could also use command line tools like grep to scan for backslashes and you can visually inspect them etc